# How to fetch the <p> tag dynamic value and pass it into typescript using angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have the below html tag in app.component.html

```
  <p id="demo">dynamicValuegoeshere!!!</p>
```

The above paragraph is having some dynamic value which is inserted by javascript. But currently i'm using type script and trying to get the above value and pass it as input argument of function.

I'm expecting the outcome like below in app.component.ts file:

```
getValue(dynamicvalue){
console.log(dynamicvalue)  //It should print the current value of the <p id="demo"> which is dynamicvaluegoeshere!!!!
}
```

can someone help me to achieve this? How can I read the particular `<P>` tag value and pass it into app.component.ts file

**Updated:**

I just used the below code to fetch the result in app.component.ts file

```
getValue()
{
 alert(document.getElementById("#demo").innerHTML);
}
```

**app.component.html**:

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" (click)="getValue()" id="submitBtn2" class="btn-primary btn-xs"`>

**Output:**

```
null
```

But the #demo still had value.

Updates-latest:

**app.component.ts :**

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })

     export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('demo', { static: false }) private dynamicRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

     getvalue() {
       return this.dynamicRef.nativeElement.innerHTML;    
    }

     alert(this.getvalue);
```

**Output:**

this.dynamicRef.nativeElement.innerHTML

[image]

**Updates - latest:**

Used `alert(this.getValue())`

**returned :**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

**Final - Working Update**:

Added #demo into the `<p>` tag which resolved this issue.

Thank you all...!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? Also, how do you call `getValue` ?

Comment: I don't know how to get the value. Googled but no luck so far.

Comment: well for start, you could use pure javascript `document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML`

Comment: I'm not sure how to get that <p> tag value. Just mentioned by my assumption. Even not sure its expected to do.

Comment: You have an Id, you could use the function `document.getElementById('demo')` or `document.querySelector('#demo')` to get a node of the `<p>` tag, the you can access the `innerHTML` property to access the content. See my previous comment.

Comment: It return null as output.

Comment: You're not calling the method, do `alert(this.getValue())`

Comment: I did that but it return error message

Comment: You can't use an alert inside of a class like that. Use a lifecycle hook, `ngAfterViewInit() { alert(this.getValue()) }`.

Comment: Tried that too. But still it returned the same error message.

Comment: What does your html template look like right now?

Comment: It looks like having some dynamic records like below:  <p _ngcontent-ugw-c0="" id="demo" >add cart id:3412342221</p>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206817/discussion-between-emontielg-and-arrchanamohan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ViewChild decorator along with a template reference and an ElementRef wrapper.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<p #dynamic>Dynamic value</p>',
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('dynamic', { static: false }) private dynamicRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  get value() {
    return this.dynamicRef.nativeElement.innerHTML;    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('value of p: ', this.value) // value of p: Dynamic value
  }
}
```

If you want to make sure the reference in the ViewChild is present when your component needs it, use the ngAfterViewInit hook instead of ngOnInit.

Here's a working example (open console): [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1z2eaz)

Comment: should I need to mentioned the template in the file? because the value of <p> is dynamic which is in app.component.html file.

Comment: No, the template can be inline or a URL, it doesn't matter.

Comment: If you want to use in ngOnInit, you need use static:true `@ViewChild('dynamic', { static: true }) private dynamicRef`

Comment: Still, its failing. Updated the question with latest finds

Comment: You need to use an angular template reference, not an HTML id. This: `<p #demo>value</p>`, not: `<p id="demo">value</p>`.